# Is there any way to know where the error occurs if the FireStore secure rule is not properly written?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**Environment:**

- Flutter
- VSCode
- Firebase

**Problem:**

I'm encountering the following error

```bash
FirebaseException ([cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.)
I'd like to identify which part of my code is generating this error.
```

**Details:**
I'm aware that this error is often due to not having set Firestore Security Rules properly. Typically, I write all the app code before setting the Firestore Security Rules, and then define the rules at the end. The challenge is, in VSCode, the error points to the exception.dart file, which makes it hard to pinpoint the actual location of the error in my code.

**Question:**
Is there a way to make VSCode halt at the actual error point in my code? Or is there a better approach I should be following to debug this?

Comment: Is the error generated on app launch? If it is, then isolating the culprit shouldn't be that time consuming. If the error is generated when a particular action is taken, then isolating the culprit should be cake, no? When does the error happen?

Comment: @trndjc Thank you for your answer. I didn't explain myself well, I was asking how to identify the line of code where this error is occurring, not a specific project or specific error.

Comment: Thank you for your nice comment. I would like to make your comment accepted answer, could you please post the content as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSCode supports live debugging with breakpoints. Breakpoints are how you halt control (flow) at the error itself. Your problem, however, is an asynchronous error that is returned through the network; it isn't generated by your source code because the error happened outside of the client. Therefore, the easiest way to debug this would be to log/print everything to the console with a file and line identifier where Firestore returns errors. I assume the reason you even see this error is because you're logging it, so just log some sort of identifier beside it so you know where it's coming from.

More specifically to VSCode, if you Google search something like "vscode log error file name line", you will find a number of ways to attach file names and file lines to logged errors. I think VSCode may even have this feature built in.

Below are some useful links.

[https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#:~:text=In%20the%20Status%20Bar%2C%20there,list%20of%20all%20current%20errors](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#:%7E:text=In%20the%20Status%20Bar%2C%20there,list%20of%20all%20current%20errors)

https://gist.github.com/kidsil/a930299e694a9653a17bd5f130dae5e6 (include the filename and line number in the console log)